# UpdateMany operation specifying filter as _id in

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a series of `ObjectIds` and I want to update a property in all documents where there's a match with the ObjectIds. So basically the SQL equivalent of:

`update collection set prop = false where id in (1,2,3)`

The Query I have built for Mongo is:

```
List<BsonValue> output = GetValues();

var builder = Builders<MyCollection>.Filter;
var filter = builder.In("_id", output);
var update = Builders<MyCollection>.Update.Set("Prop", false);
var result = myCollection.UpdateMany(filter, update);
```

However, I get the following exception when I run:

> Specified cast is not valid.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

So this query was fine... looks like the problem was with my class.

My class was:

```
public class MyCollection
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    //Other properties
}
```

Apparently the ObjectId was not being mapped correctly. I didn't have an explicit need for it so I removed it and it started working thereafter.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question so that it may help someone else in the future.

My class was:

```
public class MyCollection
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    //Other properties
}
```

The ObjectId property was not being mapped correctly. In my case, I didn't have need for it so I removed it and it started working thereafter.